# Is Silverlight a good enough platform for a Web-based operating system?

Tags: silverlight, web-operating-system

I do not work with Silverlight personally. However, I still keep an eye out on it. Silverlight 3 and the upcoming 4 has many features that seems would make it a nice web-based operating platform like out-of-browser capacities, printing support, speed, deep-zoom, multi-touch, many controls and many more. I am wondering if you think it can be a good enough platform for a web OS or if am I way off.

Comment: Silverlight 4 is not upcoming. AFAIK it is out now?

Comment: @Robert Jeppesen. Good catch. The question was asked way back in November 2009 (Silverlight 4 was just newly in Beta then). The final release came in April 2010.

Comment: I don't think Silverlight is necessary for everything: **out-of-browser** -> Mozilla Chromeless --- **printing support** -> DOM --- **deep-zoom** -> XHR + HTML5 Blobs + Canvas --- **multi-touch** -> HTML5 -- **controls** -> HTML5 `menu`/`command` element + `(-moz-)appearance`

Answer (score 0):

Can Silverlight read my hard disk? Detect my USB drive? CD ROM?

Comment: In Silverlight 4 full trust it can.

Comment: Web Operating System apart, are you suggesting that a web app is gonna be able to access my hard disk?